# How can I share data between instances in P5JS?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want be able to share data between multiple canvas instances in my P5js game.

In my first instance, I randomly generate a maze, via a backtracking algorithm.

I then want to use this maze as the blue print for my map going forwards.

My issue is that when I try to generate the algorithm in outside of my instances in the sketch.js file, so that both can use the same maze data I get the error;

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Maze is not defined
    at sketch.js:1:12
```

My scetch.js reads as following, where the top to line is my attempt to generate the maze before the instances are created;

```
let maze = new Maze(width, height, cols, rows, res);
let mazeGrid = maze.grid();

const p5Maze = ( sketch ) => {
    const width = 100;
    const height = 100;
    const res = 10;
    const cols = height / res;
    const rows = width / res;
    let maze;
    let mazeGrid;

    sketch.setup = () => {
        sketch.createCanvas(width, height);

        maze = new Maze(width, height, cols, rows, res);
        mazeGrid = maze.grid();
    };

    sketch.draw = () => {
        sketch.background(255);

        for (let r = 0; r < maze.rows; r++) {
            for (let c = 0; c < maze.cols; c++) {
                let tile = mazeGrid[r][c].tile; 

                let x1 = tile.x;
                let x2 = tile.x + maze.res;
                let y1 = tile.y;
                let y2 = tile.y + maze.res;

                if (tile.top) {
                    sketch.line(x1, y1, x2, y1);
                }
                if (tile.bottom) {
                    sketch.line(x1, y2, x2, y2);
                }
                if (tile.left) {
                    sketch.line(x1, y1, x1, y2);
                }
                if (tile.right) {
                    sketch.line(x2, y1, x2, y2);
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

let map = new p5(p5Maze, 'container');

const p5PlayArea = ( sketch ) => {
    const width = 400;
    const height = 400;
    
    sketch.setup = () => {
        sketch.createCanvas(width, height);
    };

    sketch.draw = () => {
        sketch.background(200);
    };
}

let playArea = new p5(p5PlayArea, 'screen');
```

I might well be missing something fundamental / thinking about this all wrong - any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Good idea to double check a few things first. The above code doesn't include the `Maze` class. Is that defined in the same JS file ? (If not, is it included in the same html file that loads p5 / this script (and also, that loaded / available before this script executes) ?

Comment: Its all in a different file, called Maze.js, and MazeTile.js These are included in the index.html file as follows ```<script src="maze/MazeTile.js"></script>
        <script src="maze/Maze.js"></script>```

Comment: Are these `<script>` tags loaded before p5.js and the sketch runs ? Can you try a couple of things ? 1. open the JS Console in your browser on that sketch and type `Maze` 2. Try adding `console.log(Maze);` in `setup()`. (the 1st test will tell you if the Maze class if correctly loaded: if you get same error there could be an issue loading / parsing that file, otherwise should load correctly. the 2nd test if you're still getting the same error (but accessing `Maze` in console later at runtime works) it could be the p5 sketch starts before `Maze` is loaded and ready to be used.

Comment: Do you think you can replicate your setup on https://editor.p5js.org/ ? (You can also try the snippet editor here, though it may mean copying the contents of `Maze` and `MazeTile` in the same file which won't help reproduce the loading order potential issue)